# How i can solve this circular import?

Tags: python

```
import requests

api_url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'

response1 = requests.get(api_url)

print(response1.text)
```

result:

```
response1 = requests.kwargs(api_url)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'requests' has no attribute 'kwargs' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: The error message that you show does not match the code that you show.

Comment: Two things: 1) The code you posted is calling `get`, but the error refers to `kwargs`. A [MCVE] needs to actually be reproducible and not omit/typo important things. 2) Did you happen to name your script, or a module in the same folder, `requests.py` by any chance? Normal `requests` shouldn't have a circular import involved.

Comment: its not a duplicate....

Comment: there is no similar name

Comment: what i write after requests.get or anything result is same circular import problem